# Uniform convergence for improper integrals dependig on a parameter

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

I'm having troubles to understand how apply certain covergence criteria for improper integrals. In the book "Elements of real analysis" of Robert G. Bartle we have at the problem set 25.M:

"For wich values of t do the following infinite integrals converges uniformly?"
$$a)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+t^2}$$ and
$$b)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+t}$$

My atemmp to "a)" is: Since $\dfrac{1}{x^2+t^2}\leq \dfrac{1}{x^2}$ we can use the Weirestrass M-Test but the integral depending only in $x$ diverges when the lower limit is $0$. In "b)" we can argue for $t>0$. However in several post on internet and in the "hints for the selected excercises" section of the book said that "a)" and "b)" converges uniformly for every value of $t$. Could anyone explain me this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrals diverge for any real $t \leqslant 0$, so we only need to consider uniform convergence for values of $t$ in the interval $(0,\infty)$.

For any $\alpha > 0$, both integrals are uniformly convergent for all $t \in [\alpha,\infty)$.  This follows easily from the Weierstrass M-test, since $x \mapsto (x^2 +c)^{-1}$ is integrable for any $c > 0$ and

$$\left|\frac{1}{x^2+t^2}\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{x^2 + \alpha^2}, \quad \left|\frac{1}{x^2+t}\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{x^2 + \alpha}$$

This leaves the question of uniform convergence for $t \in (0,\infty)$. If the interval of integration were $[a,\infty)$ with $a > 0$, then the convergence of both improper integrals would be unequivocally uniform by the Weierstrass M_Test since for $m = 1,2$ and all $t \in (0,\infty)$

$$\left|\frac{1}{x^2 + t^m}\right|\leqslant \frac{1}{x^2}, \quad \int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{a} < \infty$$

Furthermore, we can also argue that convergence is uniform when the interval of integration is $[0,\infty)$ despite the singular behavior of the integrand as both $x,t \to 0$.

This follows from the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence which states that the improper integral of $x \mapsto f(x,t)$ over $[0,\infty)$ is uniformly convergent for $t \in I$ if and only if the integrand is Riemann integrable over any finite interval and for every $\epsilon > 0$ and there exists $K > 0$ such that for all $c_2 > c_1 > K$ and $t \in I$ we have

$$\tag{*}\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2} f(x,t) \, dx \right|< \epsilon$$

We have already shown that for both integrands (a) and (b), the improper integrals taken over an interval such as $[1, \infty)$ are uniformly convergent for $t \in [0,\infty)$. Hence, there exists $K > 1$ for which (*) is satisfied for any $\epsilon > 0$ and all $t \in (0,\infty)$.